# Pandas DataFrame Rename Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapper

In the following line of code, df is a pandas DataFrame. When we pass the strip() function from string into mapper to clean column names, why we have to use **str.strip** instead of something like **str.strip()**. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
df=df.rename(mapper=str.strip, axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is because `str.strip` is the function, whereas `str.strip()` is the result of the function, i.e. you already call it.

In your example you want to pass the function, so `df.rename` can call the function on every column name.